# Laravel datatables - only return the requested columns, removing the additional model fields

Tags: laravel, datatables, laravel-datatables

I'm using [Laravel datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) on a website.

Data is loaded through AJAX. On my frontend code I select which columns the table needs:

```
var dataTable = $('#products-table').DataTable({
          serverSide: true,
          ajax: {
            'url': '{!! route('myroute') !!}',

          },
          columns: [
            {data: 'brand_model', orderable: false},
            {data: 'status', className: 'dt-body-center', orderable: false},
            {data: 'sale_price', className: 'dt-body-right'},
            {data: 'image_url', orderable: false, className: 'table-image'},
            {data: 'actions', orderable: false, className: 'table-actions'}
          ],
          order: [[1, "desc"]]
        });
```

On the backend, I'm currently building the response as follows:

```
$products = $user->products(); // Eloquent relationship

return DataTables::of($products)
  ->editColumn('status', function ($product) { ... })
  ->addColumn('actions', function ($product) { ... })
  ...
  ->make(true);
```

Everything is displayed correctly, **but** I analyzed the ajax response and I noticed that every column and even the `user` relationship of every product is returned. Basically, for each row in the table I return a whole bunch of useless data that **should not** be available on the frontend.

Is there a way to force the datatable builder to only include those fields and not everything else?

The only thing I could do is to only select the desired fields in the eloquent query:

```
$products = $user->products()->select(['status', 'image_url', ... ]);
```

But this solution is not feasible, because I need most of the fields and relationships to build the additional columns (i.e. `actions`). The field should be filtered **after** the required columns are built.

While an automatic solution would be perfect, I would also consider a manual solution (where I have to manually specify which fields to include in the response)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the package's default method `only`:

```
return Datatables::of($products)->->only([
            'col1',
            'col2'
        ])
```

Only the specified columns in this method will be sent in the response.